# What is the meaning of a party/event with the slogan "jingle&mingle"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slogan, motto

What will happen at this party?
Is it something with musik or marketing?

Comment: This isn't a standard phrase, that I am aware of. So it is likely that the meaning will be context dependant. If the event is happening between now and Christmas, then the 'Jingle' is probably intended to indicate the seasonality/christmassyness of the event. It would be a reference to Yule season songs such as 'Jingle bells' and 'Jingle Bell Rock'. Mingle just means 'mix together', but in party terms can be used to suggest a 'getting to know people' vibe. So I'd expect, if it fits with the context, that 'Jingle& Mingle' would be a christmassy party with people you don't necessarily know well.

Comment: Ask the person in charge of the party. This question is fairly meaningless here, with no context.

Answer (score 4):

It is an informal holiday (Christmas) party.  The person or organization inviting you to the party may or may not have an ulterior motive or agenda, but the name doesn't give you any clue to that.

[Jingle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jingle) is a word used in Christmas carols (Jingle Bells, Jingle all the Way, etc.), and it's onomatopoeia for the sound of small bells.

[Mingle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mingle) is what people do when they stand or walk around in a party and meet new people.

> to come into contact; associate
>
> to move about (as in a group) "mingled with the guests"

It's a fun and catchy name for a party because 'jingle' rhymes with 'mingle'.

Comment: Yes, the kind of answer I find really to the point rather than wandering all over the map. :)